# An Intent object doesn't work

Tags: android, android-intent, menu

I built an option menu. One of its buttons that handles sending email is not working.

Here are the methods:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_page, menu);
        return true;
    }

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings: Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the settings!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
            case R.id.exit:     System.exit(0); //close the program + kill it from memory
                                break;
            case R.id.contactUs:sendEmail();
                                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

private void sendEmail(){
        Intent mailIntent = new Intent();
        mailIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        mailIntent.setType("text/plain");
        mailIntent.putExtra(mailIntent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"some_email@gmail.com"});
        mailIntent.putExtra(mailIntent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Re:Your Application");
    }
```

For some reason, any item I clicked on, except for the contactUs item, is working.
When I click the contactUs item, it close the menu bar and does nothing...

Need help.

**EDIT:**

I changed the following:

```
private void sendEmail(){
    Intent mailIntent = new Intent();
    mailIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    mailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"some_email@gmail.com"});
    mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Re:Your Application");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mailIntent, "some_email@gmail.com"));
}
```

The fields still aren't auto-filled..

Comment: you have to start the intent, startActivity(). like startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mailIntent, "Send Email"));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to call

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mailIntent, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

Edit:

Change these lines

```
mailIntent.putExtra(mailIntent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"some_email@gmail.com"});
mailIntent.putExtra(mailIntent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Re:Your Application");
```

to

```
mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"some_email@gmail.com"});
mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Re:Your Application");
```

Edit:

Complete method should look like:

```
private void sendEmail(){
    Intent mailIntent = new Intent();
    mailIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    mailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"some_email@gmail.com"});
    mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Re:Your Application");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mailIntent, "Choose an Email client:"));
}
```

Comment: Can I add (at the bottom line of my sendEmail() method): startActivity(mailIntent); ?

Comment: Yes. Last line of your method will be startActivity(...); So your intent will be fired.

Comment: I edited this thread with another problem that prevents the app from auto fill the requested fields...

Comment: Which fields? You want to send an email, right? So did you add this "startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mailIntent, "Choose an Email client :"));" ?

Comment: Why should I use: startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mailIntent, "Choose an Email client :")); instead of just simply startActivity(mailIntent); ?

Comment: I read that thread now, and the only different is the chooser... But if I still want the app to force the default email app it doesn't matter for my app to auto-fill those 'To,subject' fields that she doesn't... I edited once again my current sendEmail() method. I really need it to be work, and I'm really want to understand what I'm doing.. the current situation is that the app works but the fields stays empty.. another question: can u explain me why I need twice mentioning the email address (last three method's lines)??

Comment: @Adam, you don't have to enter email Id in chooser argument. This is a message you want to display in a chooser popup.

Comment: Can you write down the complete method so I be able to ask questions on it ... ? thx

Comment: lets start chat...where is this line ..:P

Answer (score 2):

You need to call:

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mailIntent,"Choose E-mail client:"));
```

Comment: When I'm not using a Chooser (use this line of code: 'startActivity(mailIntent);'), It still let me choose between sms to the mail app, the only difference between your line of code to this, is the above text the on my case, it just the Android OS default one ("Complete action using")...